# .net framework 4.8 не работают функции win32 API

Tags: .net, windows-10, visual-basic

Пишу программу на VB (.net framework 4.8). В ней используются функции Win32 API (ShowWindow, SendMessage, FindWindow и т.д.). Все прекрасно работает на Windows 7 x64, а на Windows 10 эти функции вообще не хотят работать и ошибок никаких нет просто ничего не происходит и все, причем в другой программе с .net framework 4.0 эти же функции работают и на win 7 и на win 10. Кто знает что изменилось в .net framework 4.8, может их теперь объявлять как-то по другому надо или что-то включить?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился. В программе применяются функции API для управления окнами программы, которая была запущена от имени администратора. Запустил свою программу от имени администратора и все заработало на win 10. В win 7 этого не требовалось.